# How can I insert values in a 2D vector only using one of the dimensions?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I was searching how to insert values in a 2D vector and I found a really simple answer.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            int value;
            std::cout << "Value for 2D array at pos(" << i + 1 << ", " << j + 1 << "): ";
            std::cin >> value;
            arr[i].push_back(value); //<- the answer I found
        }
    }
```

I am a little confused because how can I insert a number in (i,j), if I am only giving the i?
Is j acting under the hood even though I didn't declare it when I push back the value?

Comment: @anonymous It worked for the program I built, I even printed the 2d vector to see if it was correct and it was, also, i want the value to be defined every iteration because every iteration will have a different value according to the user

Comment: Sorry for my pervious comment. I thought of the vector as an array.

Comment: In this example `j` is simply increasing and adding values to the array.  It is not inserting a value into an existing location.  Hence the `push_back`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding values to an array of arrays. 
`(arr[i])` is actually an array itself. Every `i` represents a row, and every `j` represents a column. The first for loop is iterating through the rows and the second for loop is iterating through the columns (I'm sure you knew that though). `arr[i].push_back(value)` is actually adding value to `arr[i][j]` if you want to think of it that way. The first push_back adds value to `arr[i][0]`, the second adds value to `arr[i][1]` and so on. If you had a 2D array of 0's for example, you would use `arr[i][j]`. The only reason you don't use it in this case is because if you reference `arr[i][j]` you will get an out of bounds exception since the index `j` doesn't exist yet (push_back creates it). I hope that makes sense. I thought an explanation made more sense than code since you already have the correct code and just needed an explanation.

Comment: thank you, I just wanted the explanation, and now I understand that even though i just use arr[i], since it's a 2d array (vector of vectors) it will always be looping through arr[i][j] where j is constantly changing according to the loop even though i don't specify it. Thank you so much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know the j value. Here is why, the out-most for loop iterating from 0 until the end of row. Therefore, the "i" is an index that coordinating from 0 to the end of row.

As each end of row has been reached, the inner for loop j index will move to next column.

In brief, you need only row index to fill the element in each row of 2d array, where the column is iterated to move over next column when i >= row.size.